# QML Rectangle: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead

Tags: qt, qml

i am making customized controls in the qt using the qml

tried with the previous versions of qt expect 5.11 it is working , i don't know what i need to change can any one please help

```
Rectangle{
    width: parent.width - 30
    height: 25
    anchors.leftMargin: 15
    anchors.left: parent.left
    color: "transparent"
    visible: (!auto_start)
    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text{
            text: "Frame Rate:"
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.left: parent.left
            font.pointSize: 13
            font.family: fontFamily.name
        }
        Text{
            id: framesValueLabel
            text: "0 fps"
            font.bold: true
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            font.pointSize: 13
            font.family: fontFamily.name
        }
    }
}
```

with previous versions it is working fine now the qt5.11 it is working but showing lot of warning errors in the console

Comment: explain yourself better, what is your goal ?, shows error messages, etc.

Comment: warnining message : qrc:qml/main.qml:382:4: QML Rectangle: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should not combine the anchors with the Layouts since they both fulfill similar tasks that is positioning items.

As the warning indicates:

```
Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
```

Maybe in previous versions Qt was not so smart to detect these possible errors so I did not point you out.

So the solution is to use Layout.alignment, Layout.leftMargin and Layout.rightMargin:

```
Rectangle{
    width: parent.width - 30
    height: 25
    anchors.leftMargin: 15
    anchors.left: parent.left
    color: "blue"
    visible: (!auto_start)
    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text{
            text: "Frame Rate:"
            Layout.leftMargin: 10
            Layout.alignment : Qt.AlignLeft
            font.pointSize: 13
            font.family: fontFamily.name
        }
        Text{
            id: framesValueLabel
            text: "0 fps"
            font.bold: true
            Layout.alignment : Qt.AlignRight
            Layout.rightMargin: 10
            font.pointSize: 13
            font.family: fontFamily.name
        }
    }
}
```